# Docker and Analytics Install

Tags: google-analytics, docker, dockerfile, postgres-fdw

I have a docker file called quasar.dockerfile. I built the docker file and everything loaded successfully.

```
 #quasar.dockerfile
 FROM java:8

 WORKDIR /app
 ADD docker/quasar-config.json quasar-config.json

 RUN apt-get update && \
 apt-get install -y wget && \
 wget https://github.com/quasar-analytics/quasar/releases/download/v2.3.3-SNAPSHOT-2121-web/web_2.11-2.3.3-SNAPSHOT-one-jar.jar

 EXPOSE 8080

 CMD java -jar web_2.11-2.2.3-SNAPSHOT-one-jar.jar -c /app/quasar-config.json
```

I then tried running the docker and I get this error saying that I am unable to access the jarfile.

```
 [test]$ docker build -f docker/quasar.dockerfile -t quasar_fdw_test/quasar .
 Sending build context to Docker daemon 1.851 MB
 Successfully built a7d4bc6c906f

 [test]$ docker run -d --name quasar_fdw_test-quasar --link quasar_fdw_test-mongodb:mongodb quasar_fdw_test/quasar
 6af2f58bf446560507bdf4a2db8ba138de9ed94a408492144e7fdf6c1fe05118

 [test]$ docker ps -l
 CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                    COMMAND                  CREATED                    STATUS                     PORTS               NAMES
 6af2f58bf446        quasar_fdw_test/quasar   "/bin/sh -c 'java -ja"   5 seconds ago       Exited (1) 4 seconds ago                       quasar_fdw_test-  quasar

 [test]$ docker logs 6af2f58bf446 
 Error: Unable to access jarfile web_2.11-2.2.3-SNAPSHOT-one-jar.jar
```

How come the process keeps getting killed? Seems like it has to do with being unable to run the jarfile but the build needed to access that file and happened successfully. Is this a linking issue?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use full path on Dockerfile

```
CMD java -jar /web_2.11-2.2.3-SNAPSHOT-one-jar.jar -c /app/quasar-config.json
```